# Overwriting a single (nested) property when extending a React class

Tags: reactjs, class, inheritance, antd

I am rather new to React.js, I believe I understood the major concepts, and I am struggling to find documentation on how to *overwrite a single property* of a class I am declaring.

In on of my components, I define a new class `MyColumn` based on a class from [Ant Design](https://ant.design/). The architecture (of inheritance rather than composition) was already made by others, and I am not able to change that.

```js
import { Table } from "antd";
const { Column } = Table;
// ... 
class MyColumn extends Column<Interfaces.myViewEntry> { }   // <---
```

At the moment, the column headers just flows downward, I need either ellipsis dots (and a mouse-over with the full column label), or a proper word wrap. Probably, the latter is easier.

To reach that goal, I want to set the property `style: { 'white-space': 'unset' }` (and just that property) for `MyColumn` since I read that this will allow me to get proper word-wrap for the column headers.

Could somebody please elaborate what to put into the brackets in the line I marked with `<--`?

#### Background

In `interfaces.tsx`, I defined something like the following

```
export interface myViewEntry{
    LastName: string,
    FirstName: string,
    Result: number,
}
```

#### References

- [Overwriting and Extending Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542036/overwriting-and-extending-prototype)
- [React.js: setState overwriting, not merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898012/react-js-setstate-overwriting-not-merging)
- [How to do word-wrap for data using react-table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853012/how-to-do-word-wrap-for-data-using-react-table)
- [How can we configure the Header of ant design table component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689128/how-can-we-configure-the-header-of-ant-design-table-component)
- [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)
- Reactjs-documentation on [Components and Properties](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) and on [Composition and Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

Comment: Sure. I just need more information, where inheritance exists in your code? How those components looks like?

Comment: I just checked the code again -- I guess I have to stick to inheritance. :-( There is a whole hierarchy of child classes following `MyColumn`. So composition is no option. May you still help me?

Comment: Such inheritance is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Dennis Vash: I am aware that it is not pretty, but is it technical possible? And if so, how?

Comment: Yes, you can, please provide a reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (you can use such [codesandbox-antd-template](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-antd-styled-template-n8n96) and I will show you an example accordingly.

Comment: @DennisVash I will try to do that rsn. The challenge is that the code base is really complex, and it is rather tricky to pseudonimze the code without breaking it.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion it's better to wrap ant-design components with you own ones and add additional properties to that.
For example:

```
import { Table } from 'antd';

export default function MyTableColumn({ children, ...rest }) {
  //...useState, useRef, useEffect, whatever you need.
  return <Table.Column {...rest}>{children}</Table.Column>
}
```

Comment: Is the `...rest` really three dots and not two, or does that matter at all? Could you maybe elaborate a bit on your code, I am not sure what is literal and what is placeholder. I guess, only `rest` is placeholder, am I right.

Comment: It's an object destructuring syntax, we are calling that spread operator. You can read more about that here: https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment.
And yeah, this is just an example code, you can destructure all you properties and pass them to the ant-design component

Comment: For some reason I thought the [JS spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is just two dots, like the [bash range operator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166583/bash-for-loop-with-range). I keep mixing up languages..