# Change number format of input field in Antd's table-row-edit mode?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am using the [Table Component of Ant Design v2.x](https://2x.ant.design/components/table/) and I cannot upgrade. I would like to change the formatting of numbers in row-edit mode, since currently it is inconsistent: In Display mode I have German formatting (as desired), but once I click `edit`, numbers are formatted with American decimal separators:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

I understand that the table-component encapsulates an [Input-Number component](https://2x.ant.design/ccomponents/input-number/) which has the parameter `decimalSeparator` which I have to adjust. **It is not at all obvious to me how I can pass-through that parameter from my parent (table) component column property to the underlying input-number component.**

As minimal code base to demonstrate that, let us consider the Typescript example code from https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-row and focus on the column `age`. Assume that it is not an `age`, but rather a **Value** (e.g. of a trade).
The (correct) formatting in the 2nd row of my screenshot I obtain with a `render`-function like this:

```js
x.toLocaleString("de-DE", { style: 'currency', currency: ccy, currencyDisplay: "code", maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

where `x` is the value to be formatted and `ccy` is the currency-string to be displayed, in the screenshot it was just empty.

What I *am* able to do is to specify whether a column is a `number`, a `string`, or something else. In the example source code, the corresponding part is:

```js
interface Item {
  key: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
}
```

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: The example https://codesandbox.io/s/i1bk4?file=/index.js: suggests that in the `form` of the table we could adjust the formatting. It looks like in the linked example, an `EditableCell` is constructed, which is handed over to the table which in turn uses that as editor. I am just not quite sure how to adjust my existing, inherited code to that. Inherited is meant quite literally here, but that's a different issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285455/

Comment: I can help to adjust your code if you provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trial and error, I finally understood how the `formatter` and `parser` of the  `InputNumber` component works, there was close to no documentation at https://2x.ant.design/components/table/

I ended up doing the following, which is not exactly pretty, but works:

```
<InputNumber
  defaultValue={this.props.value !== null ? parseFloat(this.props.value) : null}
  // This is what 2x.antd.design suggests to do it:
  // formatter={value => ` ${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')}
  // parser={value => value.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)/g, "")}

  // This my solution for German numbers
  formatter={value => ` ${value}`.replace(/\./,',').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.')}
  parser={x => parseFloat(`${x}`.replace(/,/, '#').replace(/\./g, '').replace(/#/,'.')) }  

  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

The idea of the `formatter` is to first replace the decimal separator `.` with `,`. The `replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')` is to find globally all 3-digit groups `\d{3}`, and replace any kind of thousand-separator with `.`, the `\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))` finds all but the last `,`.

Before writing things back into the state variable `this.props.value`, we have to undo that replacement, so we first replace the comma as decimal separator with some placeholder `#`, then delete all `.` in the string, and finally make revert the placeholder to the `.` as decimal separator which can be understood by [`parseFloat`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp).

Comment: @oozywaters I figured it out myself, but it was indeed not straight-forward. Are my explanations making sense?

Answer (score 3):

`InputNumber` has `formatter` and `parser` props that you can use to format currency values.

Another easier option, that I would recommend, is to use input mask. Here is an example involving [react-number-format](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";
import { Table, Input, Form } from "antd";

const EditableCell = ({
  editing,
  dataIndex,
  title,
  inputType,
  record,
  index,
  children,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const inputNode =
    inputType === "number" ? (
      <NumberFormat
        customInput={Input}
        thousandSeparator="."
        decimalSeparator=","
        decimalScale={2}
      />
    ) : (
      <Input />
    );
  return (
    <td {...restProps}>
      {editing ? (
        <Form.Item
          name={dataIndex}
          style={{
            margin: 0
          }}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: `Please Input ${title}!`
            }
          ]}
        >
          {inputNode}
        </Form.Item>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </td>
  );
};
```

Also, you can check out a live example [over here](https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-rows-with-formatting-ant-design-demo-19nrk).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, may you explain a bit what an input-mask is and what the idea behind your suggestion is? My issue is that I am not so fluent with reatjs-specific terms - sorry for that, it is just not my native language :-)

Comment: Input mask is not a react specific term. You can refer to this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_mask for more information. There are several implementations of input mask for reactjs, such as react-input-mask, react-text-mask and react-number-format, mentioned in the answer. The idea behind my suggestion is to avoid implementing complex `formatter` and `parser` functions by yourself and take advantage of ready solutions in spite of causing an extra dependency.

Answer (score -1):

Please use

```
const formatValue = value => value.toLocaleString("en-IN");
```

You can get the desired format from fromate LocaleString.

```
ar-SA Arabic (Saudi Arabia)
bn-BD Bangla (Bangladesh)
bn-IN Bangla (India)
cs-CZ Czech (Czech Republic)
da-DK Danish (Denmark)
de-AT Austrian German
de-CH "Swiss" German
de-DE Standard German (as spoken in Germany)
el-GR Modern Greek
en-AU Australian English
en-CA Canadian English
en-GB British English
en-IE Irish English
en-IN Indian English
en-NZ New Zealand English
en-US US English
en-ZA English (South Africa)
es-AR Argentine Spanish
es-CL Chilean Spanish
es-CO Colombian Spanish
es-ES Castilian Spanish (as spoken in Central-Northern Spain)
es-MX Mexican Spanish
es-US American Spanish
fi-FI Finnish (Finland)
fr-BE Belgian French
fr-CA Canadian French
fr-CH "Swiss" French
fr-FR Standard French (especially in France)
he-IL Hebrew (Israel)
hi-IN Hindi (India)
hu-HU Hungarian (Hungary)
id-ID Indonesian (Indonesia)
it-CH "Swiss" Italian
it-IT Standard Italian (as spoken in Italy)
ja-JP Japanese (Japan)
ko-KR Korean (Republic of Korea)
nl-BE Belgian Dutch
nl-NL Standard Dutch (as spoken in The Netherlands)
no-NO Norwegian (Norway)
pl-PL Polish (Poland)
pt-BR Brazilian Portuguese
pt-PT European Portuguese (as written and spoken in Portugal)
ro-RO Romanian (Romania)
ru-RU Russian (Russian Federation)
sk-SK Slovak (Slovakia)
sv-SE Swedish (Sweden)
ta-IN Indian Tamil
ta-LK Sri Lankan Tamil
th-TH Thai (Thailand)
tr-TR Turkish (Turkey)
zh-CN Mainland China, simplified characters
zh-HK Hong Kong, traditional characters
zh-TW Taiwan, traditional characters
```